# mysql_do_db appears to be being ignored on Ubuntu

Tags: mysql

I have master/slave replication running. I only want it to replicate the `mydb` database. This is the master config.

```
[mysqld]
bind-address=0.0.0.0
server-id=1
binlog_do_db=mydb
log_bin=/var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days=10
max_binlog_size=100M
binlog_ignore_db = mysql
```

The master appears to be completely ignoring the `binlog_do_db=mydb`.

```
mysql> SHOW MASTER STATUS;
+---------------+----------+--------------+------------------+-------------------+
| File          | Position | Binlog_Do_DB | Binlog_Ignore_DB | Executed_Gtid_Set |
+---------------+----------+--------------+------------------+-------------------+
| binlog.000013 |      446 |              |                  |                   |
+---------------+----------+--------------+------------------+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Further, it's ignoring this too `log_bin=/var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log` as there's no `mysql-bin.log` in the `/var/log/mysql/` folder.

Running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and MySQL 8.0.28-0ubuntu0.20.04.3.

Comment: I hope that `**` is not in the file.

Comment: ** is not in the file - question updated.

Comment: And you performed a `CHANGE MASTER` on the Replica to get replication started?  What does it's `SHOW SLAVE STATUS` say?